# How to create a parameterless indexer

Tags: c#, properties

I might have coded myself into a corner here, but I am hoping there is a simple way out of it.

My Logic Layer is a static singleton instance that has lots of properties for accessing the individual sub-Logic Layers. Most of this was put in place for unit testing to allow injection of custom repositories and works quite nicely for that. However the boiler plate code for each sub-instance is very repetitive and I would expect that there is a way to simplify it.

Below is a very simplified example to demonstrate how far I have manages to get and where I am stuck. The one way that works is with an indexer on the sub-logic class wrapper to get to the sub-logic, which reads very strangely. The other way is by using a random letter as a property on the sub-logic class wrapper to get to the sub-logic. This reads slightly better, but still has a ripple effect on all the existing code.

Can this be done the way I want to, or should I be looking at this completely differently.
Apologies for the length of the example. I tried to make it as simple as possible while still keeping the concept intact

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logic = new Logic();
        // old usage (desired)
        var abcs_1 = logic.ABCs_1.List();
        var defs_1 = logic.DEFs_1.List();
        // new usage (would like to keep old way)
        var abcs_2 = logic.ABCs_2[0].List(); // <-- ugly
        var defs_2 = logic.DEFs_2.d.List();  // <-- less ugly, but still not pretty
        //var abcs_2 = logic.ABCs_2.List(); // <-- wanted
        //var defs_2 = logic.DEFs_2.List();  // <-- wanted
    }
}

public class ABC { }

public class DEF { }

public class ABCsLogicLayer
{
    public List<ABC> List() { return null; }
}

public class DEFsLogicLayer
{
    public List<DEF> List() { return null; }
}

public class Logic
{
    #region New Code. Want to move towards this
    public LogicLocker<ABCsLogicLayer> ABCs_2 = new LogicLocker<ABCsLogicLayer>();
    public LogicLocker<DEFsLogicLayer> DEFs_2 = new LogicLocker<DEFsLogicLayer>(); 
    #endregion

    #region Old Code. Want to move away from this.

    #region BuilerPlate for ABCs_1
    private ABCsLogicLayer m_ABCs = null;
    private readonly object m_ABCsLock = new object();
    public ABCsLogicLayer ABCs_1
    {
        get
        {
            lock (m_ABCsLock)
            {
                if (m_ABCs == null)
                {
                    m_ABCs = new ABCsLogicLayer();
                }
            }
            return m_ABCs;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (m_ABCsLock)
            {
                m_ABCs = value;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region BuilerPlate for DEFs_1
    private DEFsLogicLayer m_DEFs = null;
    private readonly object m_DEFsLock = new object();
    public DEFsLogicLayer DEFs_1
    {
        get
        {
            lock (m_DEFsLock)
            {
                if (m_DEFs == null)
                {
                    m_DEFs = new DEFsLogicLayer();
                }
            }
            return m_DEFs;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (m_DEFsLock)
            {
                m_DEFs = value;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion
}

public class LogicLocker<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private T LogicLayer = null;
    private readonly object LogicLayerLock = new object();

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (LogicLayerLock)
            {
                if (LogicLayer == null)
                {
                    LogicLayer = new T();
                }
            }
            return LogicLayer;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (LogicLayerLock)
            {
                LogicLayer = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public T d
    {
        get
        {
            lock (LogicLayerLock)
            {
                if (LogicLayer == null)
                {
                    LogicLayer = new T();
                }
            }
            return LogicLayer;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (LogicLayerLock)
            {
                LogicLayer = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parameterless indexer"? parameterless indexer is a property

Comment: Where is the difference between "ugly" and "wanted" in your code?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Thanks. Updated the code to reflect what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface for solve your problem:
1) Define interface with List method:

```
public interface ILogicLayer<T>
{
    List<T> List();
}
```

2) Your logic layer class should implement this interface:

```
public class ABCsLogicLayer:ILogicLayer<ABC>
```

3) LogicLocker should implement this interface as well

```
public class LogicLocker<T,U> : ILogicLayer<U> where T : ILogicLayer<U>, new()
```

Implementation of List method will be:

```
lock (LogicLayerLock)
{
    if (LogicLayer == null)
    {
         LogicLayer = new T();
    }
}
return LogicLayer.List();
```

4) You will instantiate your logic locker in the `Logic` class

```
public LogicLocker<ABCsLogicLayer, ABC> ABCs_2 = new LogicLocker<ABCsLogicLayer,ABC>();
public LogicLocker<DEFsLogicLayer, DEF> DEFs_2 = new LogicLocker<DEFsLogicLayer, DEF>();
```

or better make it more generics:

```
public LogicLocker<LogicLayer<ABC>> ABCs_2 = new LogicLocker<LogicLayer<ABC>>();
```

but it depends on what you want